# WPF/Silverlight Conditional Styles

Tags: wpf, silverlight

Given the object graph below I need to have 2 different style applied depending on whether the Parent object has any children or not.

I am unsure how to go about setting the style on a condition like this, can anyone help please?

```
Parent (Object)
 Prop1 (string)
 Prop2 (string)
    Children (List<Object>)
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using a IValueConverter and bind that to the Style property, passing the current object as a conversion parameter.  Within your IValueConverter, return the correct style.

Alternatively, you could use a DataTemplateSelector and swap DataTemplates based on Children.Count.  I don't know enough about your objects/properties to know whether you're in need of a different DataTemplate or a different style for the same DataTemplate.

Comment: Selectors probably aren't a good bet because the selector won't re-run if a child is added or removed.  Also it's not clear whether he's in WPF or Silverlight, but if it's Silverlight, I think that doesn't have selectors.